# How to encode a word report from knitr?

Tags: r, encoding, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown

I Built a function with r markdown that creates a report in Word (in Hebrew), the report comes out as Hebrew, but symbols and numbers comes out formatted as english. that makes the document inconsistent through the entire document.

An example of the r markdown code is as follows:

````
 ---
 title: "3.5.17" 
 fig.align: "right"
 output:
    word_document:
     reference_docx: desin_word_documents.docx
 params:
   n: NA
   konan: NA
 ---
 ```{r example, include=FALSE}
    eg_heb <- "שלום עולם"
    num_heb <- 123
    sym_heb <- "!"
 ```
 בתכנות נוהגים לתת לתלמידים כמשימה ראשונה להדפיס על המסך את הביטוי ```r eg_heb```
לעיתים עם הסימן ```r sym_heb``` או עם המספרים ```r num_heb```
````

I know that the direction of the text is reverse, that's Okay, I already solved it, and in the end of my code it comes out Okay.

Also, I didn't include the "params" in the example that **is** included in my original code.

I work with:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255    
LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255 

other attached packages:
 [1] shiny_1.0.0          gridExtra_2.2.1      ReporteRs_0.8.8      
ReporteRsjars_0.0.2  shinyBS_0.61         XLConnect_0.2-12    
 [7] XLConnectJars_0.2-12 reshape2_1.4.2       dplyr_0.5.0          
ggplot2_2.2.1        xlsx_0.5.7           xlsxjars_0.6.1      
 [13] rJava_0.9-8          readxl_0.1.1
```

I tried to attach a document showing the problem, but since I wasn't able to, if anyone is interested I'll send him a word document with the problem.

I suspect the problem is in the formatting in word or in the encoding **into** word

thank you in advance,

Aharon.